# How i can set the time in the title of push notifications? Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

In the title of the push notifications of other apps, i can see the time in the right corner of the push. I've attached a image: the first notification has the time properly, and the second not (it is the mine haha).

[image]

This is my code:

```
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification;

                int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

                if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                {
                    // Do something for HONEYCOMB and above versions
                    notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .build();
                } else{
                    // do something for phones running an SDK before HONEYCOMB
                    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, context.getString(R.string.app_name), System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
```

Also i am using the method setShowWhen(true).

Really, i don't know what I can do!!!